# Manipulate, Import external table, save as CDF, mail presentation

Tags: export, manipulate, syntax, cdf-format, data-acquisition

For my work I do data analysis. Most of these analysis are done on big databases with milions of records. **I would like to make a manipulate (or animate) using a external dataset and create a CDF without sending this external dataset to other people.**

As import syntax I use:

```
data = Import["E:\\file\\filename.TXT", 
  "Table", {"FieldSeparators" -> "|", "CharacterEncoding" -> "ASCII", 
   "HeaderLines" -> 1, "EmptyField" -> "", 
   "RepeatedSeparators" -> False}]
```

Examples of the imported dataset are:

> {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 297}, {1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 5}, {1, 3, 
>     1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1310}, {2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 51}, {2, 3, 1, 
>     2, 2, 5}, {3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1894}, {3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 164}, {3, 3, 1, 2, 
>     2, 23}, {3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2656}, {4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 
>     295}, {4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 34}, {4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 5}, {4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 
>     1}, {4, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 2693}, {5, 2, 2, 5, 4, 
>     400}, {5, 3, 2, 4, 3, 70}, {5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 16}

I wrote this syntax to create a `Manipulate`

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[
  {Select[data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], #[[1]] == bonbedrag &][[All, {2, 3}]], 
   Select[data[[All, {1, 2, 4}]], #[[1]] == bonbedrag &][[All, {2, 3}]], 
   Select[data[[All, {1, 2, 5}]], #[[1]] == bonbedrag &][[All, {2, 3}]]},
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, FillingStyle ->  LightBrown, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, , Thick}, {Blue, Thick}, {Green, Dashed, Thick}},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"ondergrens", "bovengrens", "gemiddeld"}, Below], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 2,
  AxesLabel -> {Style["aantal artikelen gekocht", Bold, Red], 
    Style["prijs duurste artikel", Bold, Blue]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotLabel -> Style[Framed[StringForm["Bonbedrag = Euro `1`", bonbedrag]]],
  GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 200}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
  ],
 {bonbedrag, 1, 200, 1}]
```

The result is the next picture

[image: example manipulate]

Then I save the presentation in CDF format, without the import-syntax. When I send the presentation it doesn't work. **Can somebody help me how to deal with external files in a manipulate syntax?**

Comment: Do your recipients have copies of *Mathematica* or Wolfram *Player Pro*?  I do not believe it is possible to import data in a CDF without one of those.

Comment: [related - load big data to CDF](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26234/5478)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Data import and export are not supported from within CDF Player with the exception of Wolfram-curated data sources (ChemicalData, CountryData, WordData, etc.).
>
> Because CDF Player cannot load custom data at runtime, you must ensure that all necessary information is embedded within the interactive elements of your .cdf file. This can be done with either Initialization or SaveDefinitions; both are options to Manipulate.

– from [the Mathematica How-To](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/CreateAComputableDocumentFormatFile.html)

Answer (score 0):

[This screencast](http://youtu.be/RhYoWRT2yPk) shows the main features of an application for data importing and analysis in Mathematica.  Although data importing is not shown in the screencast the application has a very nice interface for data importing from databases, spreadsheets and other data formats or sources.  BEST Viewpoints can be used to standardize many common data mining and analytics tasks.  You can download a trial version [from here](http://www.prontoanalytics.com/fdownloads.php).

Comment: Please disclose your job relationship with the product maker in each answer promoting it. Also, try to keep that kind of marketing at a minimum.