# Conceal GUI source code

Tags: cdf-format

I'm working with a simple software application written in *Mathematica*, composing of several .nb and .m files. The application is centered around a simple mathematica GUI, which includes several numerical input fields and selection options, and produces output graphs.

What I wish to do is keep this GUI, but somehow hide the source code so that a user (who would access the machine remotely) cannot edit or see the algorithm producing the GUI.

I know two potential options may be converting to .CDF or recompiling the mathematica code into C.  I'm interested in any other possibilities, but I have two specific questions based on these options:

- Can I export multiple .m and .nb files into a single .CDF, and if so would there be any way to view the algorithms underlying the GUI?
- If I compile the mathematica code into C, would it still be able to produce a GUI?

Comment: Related: [Seeking strategies to deploy a function securely without a front end](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17634/seeking-strategies-to-deploy-a-function-securely-without-a-front-end)

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1571/131 (plus assorted related links). Compiling to C will be only feasible for a small subset of functions.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/wolfram-cdf-virtual-workshop-2012/videos/real-world-applications/