# Program hidden beneath an interface in mathematica

Tags: gui-construction, interface

I recently wrote a mathematica code that I would like to distribute to some friends. However, I don't want to give away the code. Is there a way that I can hide the code beneath an interface kind of like a GUI, in mathematica. I would simply just like a button that says run and then gives the results on the screen. I looked around and couldn't figure out how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Your CDF code will allow anyone to read the code by inspecting the cell that contains it.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [(1571)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1571/121), [(58471)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58471/121)

Comment: Do your friends have Mathematica?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I so wish Wolfram would empower users to hide code through CDF.  It would *greatly* expand the usage of *Mathematica*, I believe.  WRI Support tells me the only way to do this is with the Corporate version of *Mathematica* which is far too expensive for mere users.  (We can only hope that v. 11 will permit it.)