# How to save the result in the Notebook (.nb) and shut down the computer when the calculation is done

Tags: front-end, notebooks, save, scheduling

I have a notebook(.nb) which its calculation is time-consuming and long. I can not observe it if the calculation is done or not.
Therefore, I want to :

1. Save the results in the notebook(.nb) ( I do not want to save the data in a .Xls,.CSV,... file) and then
2. Use a command in that notebook(.n) to shut down the computer from *Mathematica* when the calculation and saving the data is done.

I wonder if you could possibly help me with this problem.

P.S: I have already searched the documentation and found `NotebookSave[]` command, but I'm not sure if it is a proper command to save the notebook. However, I couldn't find anything relate to shuting down the computer after calculation.

Comment: I think a similar question has been asked before, but I neither remember it clearly nor the solution if any was given.

Comment: I suspect best way to shut down will be to use a command line script.  What OS are you running?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: The OS is " Windows 8 ". So you mean there is no way ?!

Comment: I didn't say there was no way, and I don't think the question should be deleted.  I mean that you will probably need to use something like:  `Run["shutdown /s"]` to shut down.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I used `Run[Logoff]` and it somehow worked. However, `Run[Shutdown]` didn't.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - I think you may have remembered: [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8392/programmatically-quitting-the-frontend-or-running-without-one)

Comment: @Jagra That's probably what it was, and clearly this is not a duplicate.  Thanks.

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/162305/1463976)? `Run[...]` should work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Windows this works for me:

```
Pause[1];
1 + 1       (*you can add Save or Export here ofc*)
NotebookSave @ EvaluationNotebook[];
Run["shutdown -t 2 -s"];

NotebookClose[]
```

For command explanation take a look at the link Öskå has provided:

[SO:162305](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162304/how-do-i-shutdown-restart-logoff-windows-via-bat-file/162305#162305)