# Can FrontEndTokenExecute["Close"] work without a pop-up window?

Tags: front-end

I wanted to make the notebook automatically be saved and closed after an evaluation of all cells. So, I found a way to add at the end of the code:

```
FrontEndTokenExecute["Save"]
FrontEndTokenExecute["Close"]
```

If I run all cells at once, all cells will be evaluated and automatically be saved in the end. However, the FrontEndToken "Close" asks me if I want to close or not.

How can I make this be just closed without the question-pop-up?

Comment: `NotebookClose[]`?

Comment: @Kuba That works perfect! So simple! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This and more: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56780/5478