# How can one *force* a front end session to *terminate itself* programmatically?

Tags: front-end, programming

**NB:** None of the responses to [Programmatically quitting the FrontEnd or running without one?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8392/2464) answers the question asked here.

---

If one runs `FrontEndTokenExecute["FrontEndQuit"]`, *Mathematica* pops up a dialog about a "running evaluation", etc.  This behavior pauses the program's execution indefinitely, which rules out this approach for terminating the front end programmatically.

Is there a way around this?

Acceptable strategies include:

1. suppressing the dialog altogether;
2. clicking on its OK button programmatically (though I suspect this may be impossible to do from within the front end session itself);
3. using some way other than `FrontEndTokenExecute["FrontEndQuit"]` to programmatically terminate the front end.

Comment: Just kidding: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40737/47416

Comment: @Shadowray: segfault, is that the idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid "running evaluation" dialog is to schedule the shutdown using `RunScheduledTask`:

```
RunScheduledTask[FrontEndTokenExecute["FrontEndQuit"], 1];
```

Note that you still have to save all notebooks first, otherwise you will get a "save" dialog.

Comment: Thanks!  It works even with a 0-second "delay".